# How to access positions of data frames within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract

I made a list of data.frames the following way:

```
dflist <- list()

for (i in 1:24) {
  name <- paste("tp",i,sep="")
  assign(name, read.csv(paste(i, "c.csv", sep=""), sep  = ";", header = TRUE))
  dflist[[i]] <- name
}
```

the list looks like this:

```
> dflist
[[1]]
[1] "tp1"

[[2]]
[1] "tp2"
```

and the data.frames like this:

```
> tp1
   X..     X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9    X10    X11    X12
1    A 0.0463 0.0503 0.0478 0.0499 0.0501 0.0499 0.0495 0.0505 0.0491 0.0520 0.0492 0.0509
2    B 0.0503 0.0508 0.0495 0.0494 0.0498 0.0501 0.0497 0.0492 0.0496 0.0497 0.0495 0.0496
```

how can i now access specific elements of my data.frames?

```
dflist[[1]][1,1]
```

does not work..
i searched in other answers, but i somehow don't get the often suggested 'lapply' function to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `assign`in the first place. If you do you will need `get`.

```
get(dflist[[1]])[1, 1]
```

And this is, at best, uggly. And you will have 24 df's wandering around the global environment for you to process.
Much better is to use `lapply` and store them all in your `dflist`, not just their names.

```
dflist <- lapply(1:24, function(i){
        read.csv(paste(i, "c.csv", sep=""), sep  = ";")
})

names(dflist) <- paste("tp", 1:24, sep="")

dflist$tp1[1, 1]
```

Also, do you have `sep = ";"` because this comes from countries where the decimal marker is the comma? If so you can use the other version of the function to read in the data, `read.csv2`. You won't have to set it manually. (And they both assume `header = TRUE` as the default.)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I didnt realize i was just storing the names haha.. and i will be using read.csv2 from now on. again thank you!

Comment: fun fact: i'm from switzerland and i just learned that it's the only country which uses both comma and point as decimal marker depending on the situation.

Comment: @ElArk So you have to be careful. In case of doubt you can use `read.table`, which is the function that both `read.csv` and `read.csv2` call after setting the values of some arguments. I suggest that you read the respective help page. But then you will have a bit more work to do.